# Result of a FormField returns empty in macro after value entered in word template

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros, form-fields

I have a Microsoft Word 2010 Template file with several FormFields on it.  There are three at the top for Project Name, Project Location, and Project Number.  I intend to intercept the FileSave built-in macro and concatenate the values of the three fields mentioned above to suggest a file name in the save-as dialog.  My code consists of:

```
Sub FileSave()

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = ThisDocument.FormFields("ProjectNumber").Result & _
                ThisDocument.FormFields("ProjectName").Result & _
                ThisDocument.FormFields("ProjectLocation").Result
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

When I fill out the three fields and press ctrl+s, the save-as dialog indeed appears, but the filename is blank.  Upon further investigation in the Immediate window, I can refer to these fields, but their Result property always return an empty string.  Thus the filename in the dialog appears blank.  I can refer to the boolean properties, the Type property, etc. and display that in a MsgBox via the Immediate window, I just can't get it to return anything for Result.  Does anyone have an idea of why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the answer to this question ended up being this:  I was still working inside a template document, and not a macro-enabled document.  For templates, during a macro's run-time, the fields on the document do not contain values.  In order for macros to be able to use values entered into FormFields, it has to be a document and not a template.  Hope this helps anyone in search of this question being answered.